# HB Silver ebank online

Tags: online-banking

I have an account with HB Silver ebank online which another person set up for me. My questions are these: 1) Is this a legitmate bank system?, 2)My account shows funds in it, are these funds actually there or fake? A little more information on this account. My friend was working in Milan, Italy when he set up his account and mine. The website is hbsiver.com. When I open it, it takes me to a page to sign in on. Let me know if further information is needed. Thank you,

Comment: scam. walk away. If you have never met that "friend" in person then in all likelihood that person doesn't actually exist. Even if you have, may have been an imposter.

Answer (score 2):

If someone else sets up an account for you, you can pretty darned safely assume it's a scam. A legitimate bank would want you to set up your own account.

Lookup suggests hbsilver.com is managed through GoDaddy, behind a layer of anonymity. Not what one would expect from a legitimate bank.

The fact that their site is also the *only* site which mentions them, in a quick websearch, also suggests they don't exist.

Run.